# С# Масштабирование нарисованого на PictureBox (SizeMode - Zoom)

Tags: c#, winforms, масштабирование

Я рисую Rectangle на PictureBox у которого SizeMode = Zoom. Как мне при изменении размеров PictureBox, изменять размер и позицию Rectangle? Как применить Zoom к Rectangle? Как получить новые координаты и размер?
Проект winforms.

```
private void box_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  foreach (Marker marker in markers) {
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red) {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, marker.getZone());
    }
  }
}
```

Мне нужно записывать координаты относительно PictureBox.Image.Size?

Comment: считать самому, где и как рисовать квадрат

Comment: @Igor да к сожалению(

Comment: @Igor нужно узнать новые точки и размер Rectangle

Comment: Вы, вроде, не первый день на форуме, а вопросы до сих пор задавать не научились: не приводите код, который используете. Это WinForms? Рисуете в [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx)? Смотрите его методы, содержащие слово `Transform`. В первую очередь `ScaleTransform`.

Comment: Как вариант, рисовать непосредственно на `Image`/`Bitmap`. Тогда рисунок будет масштабироваться вместе с ним.

Comment: Вручную координаты рассчитываются тоже элементарно. Пропорции в школе классе в пятом-шестом проходят.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Добавил. Мне нужно знать координаты, я не понимаю что просходит при Zoom

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Igor оно только SizeMode установить может?

Comment: Свойство `SizeMode` применяется только к изображению, которое лежит в свойстве `Image`. Все, что вы рисуете событии `Paint`, не управляется данным свойством, так что, только ручками. Либо рисовать непосредственно на изображении из `Image`, но это не самый удачный вариант, т.к. эти изменения будут сохранены на изображении до тех пор, пока вы его не загрузите в `PictureBox` заново. Лучше бы описали что именно хотите сделать, а `PictureBox` это не редактор, это просто "продвинутый" `Label`, где вместо текста картинка.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, нужно определить для каких размеров PictureBox заданы размеры маркеров, которые вы рисуете.

Если, например, маркеры задаются перед показом PictureBox и никогда не меняются, то начальные размеры PictureBox можно считать опорной точкой. Для этого их необходимо сохранить в переменную.

При изменении размеров PictureBox, у нас получаются две [пропорции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)):

```
old_picturebox_width/new_picturebox_width=marker_width/rectangle_width
old_picturebox_height/new_picturebox_height=marker_height/rectangle_height
```

Таким образом, чтобы определить факторы, на который следует умножать оригинальные ширину и высоту маркера, надо всего лишь разделить оригинальные ширину и высоту PictureBox на его текущие ширину и высоту (и не забыть проверку на ноль; если ноль - делить нельзя, но и рисовать слава богу тоже не надо).

Если маркеры задаются пользователем (то есть изменяются), тогда лучше поступить по другому. Вычислять размеры маркеров нужно не непосредственно перед их отрисовкой, а сразу после изменения размеров PictureBox. Для этого, надо запоминать предыдущие размеры PictureBox, при изменении размеров заменять предыдущие маркеры вновь посчитанными с учетом пропорции, и запоминать текущие размеры PictureBox, чтобы использовать их когда размеры PictureBox изменятся снова.

Comment: marker_width = (old_picturebox_width/new_picturebox_width) * rectangle_width и так с height?